# Failed to connect to MongoDB ( remote server )

Tags: node.js, angular

I am trying to deploy an Angular/NodeJS app on the server I just bought.
( http://o2switch.fr is the provider )
I managed to deploy the angular part, but I have trouble with the connexion to mongoDB

When I launch app.js in my terminal, it says :

```
(node:30382) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [cluster0-shard-00-00.cgjma.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 15.237.158.132:27017]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/home/ewhc6963/nodevenv/node/10/lib/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:441:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at createConnection (/home/ewhc6963/nodevenv/node/10/lib/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:564:14)
    at connect (/home/ewhc6963/nodevenv/node/10/lib/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:1014:9)
    at makeConnection (/home/ewhc6963/nodevenv/node/10/lib/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:32:7)
    at callback (/home/ewhc6963/nodevenv/node/10/lib/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:300:5)
    at TLSSocket.err (/home/ewhc6963/nodevenv/node/10/lib/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:330:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
(node:30382) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:30382) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Basically, it doesn't manage to connect to MongoDB even though in localhost, it works fine.

app.js :

```
mongoose.connect(config.DB_URI, function(err, db){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Connected to database');
}, { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

config/server.js :

```
module.exports = {
    DB_URI : 'mongodb+srv://pseudo:password@cluster0.cgjma.mongodb.net/rank'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongo connection fails. So you should handle the promise rejection. You may use `.catch()` method to do that. You can check [this link](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#error-handling).

Comment: I managed to sort this out, but now it says everything is ok,  but going to the url example.com/node, which is the root for the app, says Cannot GET /node, although there are routes and everything, it must be something to do with the port.

Comment: I can't be sure what its about without seeing the codebase. You can open another question with related code blocks to get help. If the answer solves the previous problem can you approve it please ?